# changing the openId metadata on .net botframework

Tags: .net, botframework

Can you change the openIdMetadata URI in bot framework Connector for .NET?

For example, in NodeJS is quite simple and you have two ways:

- Change the default value (pseudo-constant) in the /botbuilder/lib/bots/ChatConnector.js (As JS is not compiled text it is simple)
- Or use the normal way authorized by Microsoft: pass this value in settings of the ChatConnector instance construction

For example:

```
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
   appId: "GUID",
   appPassword: "password",
   openIdMetadata: "https://url"
});
```

Thank you in advance and if I can provide more info, please tell me.

Comment: May I ask what your use case is here?

Comment: I have my own implementation of the bot connector. As long as the connector is localhost, all works well, but if I wanna deploy the connector separately, every message must be validated with Microsoft. I have OAuth2 internally and i want to perform this validation in-house

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response.  It looks like you would need to be using local code instead of the NuGet packages which you can learn about how to do in this [blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/03/debug-bot-builder-source/).  You would need to change this property [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/b7d9b2e2bf26e918dc507167d3c868ee0e8d2b43/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/JwtConfig.cs#L24)

```
public const string ToBotFromChannelOpenIdMetadataUrl = "https://login.botframework.com/v1/.well-known/openidconfiguration";
```